# Debugging my program

Tags: c++, debugging

Each time I run this method it keeps returning my error message outputted. For example:
User input:

```
display <table.txt> sortedby <ID>
```

This is the correct syntax I wanted the user to use when calling the display function. But when the user types display using the correct syntax it outputs my specified error message.

```
 Syntax error: display <intable> sortedby <col_name>
```

Overall in this method I want the table displayed in a pretty format. But it doesn't go past the if statement. I was wondering if there is something I'm overlooking that might return my error_message.

```
 void display(Lexer lexer) {
  Table table; // create a table from the created table class
  vector<Token> tokvec = lexer.tokenize();



// expect [IDENT | STRING] sortedby IDENT
 if (tokvec.size() != 4 ||
    (tokvec[0].type != IDENT && tokvec[1].type != STRING) ||
    tokvec[2].value != "sortedby" || tokvec[3].type != IDENT){
    error_return("Syntax error: display <intable> sortedby <col_name>");
    return;
 }


    string fn = tokvec[1].value; // name of the file
    string col_name = tokvec[3].value;
    table.set_input(fn);
    table.scan_input();
    table.set_index(col_name);
    table.sort();
    table.display();
```

}

Comment: There's a bug in `tokenize()` that's difficult to spot from here. Doesn't setting a breakpoint on the `error_return` line work?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you print out every value being compared in the if statement. One of them is true when it should be false, so you need to find out which one it is. Once you've done that, figure out which value is what it shouldn't be, and trace the error to its source.

Something like this:

```
cout << tokvec.size() <<  " doesn't equal " << 4 << " - " << tokvec.size() != 4 << endl;
cout << tokvec[0].type << " doesn't equal " << IDENT << " - " << tokvec[0].type != IDENT << endl;
```

Etc.

This will print out each statement being made, followed by whether or not it is true. It should make it clear where the problem is.